# Firebase and Ionic read single value for attendance count

Tags: html, arrays, ionic-framework, firebase

Here is a plunker for my [app](http://plnkr.co/edit/pNG8qQGDYtPg55wyXgzK?p=preview).

I am working on a mobile app using Ionic. In the app I have a section which tells users that there are X people attending this function. It then asks if they would like to attend, if so it adds them as people attending. I am planning on using Firebase to do this as it will keep track of the people attending.

However in trying to make this work I have run into issues at every turn. For now I was mainly working on getting it to just display a count of the people coming. The code I have for that is this:

```
<div class="list card">
  <div class="item item-calm item-divider">Deliver Meals on Saturday</div>
  <div class="item item-body" ng-repeat="item in items |filter:'1'">
  <p>Hey, there are {{item.name}} people attending.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the code for the controller for that page.

```
.controller('HelpCtrl', function($scope, Items) {
$scope.items = Items;
});
```

This is the factory I was using to create my items list.

```
.factory("Items", function($firebaseArray) {
var itemsRef = new Firebase("https://example.com/items");
return $firebaseArray(itemsRef);
})
```

All that shows in the final product is a card with the title "Deliver Meals on Saturday" and it acts like the controller has disappeared.

All I really need is for there to be a card in my app which uses my firebase account to say, "There are x people attending." if the hit submit it then prints to everyone else, "There are (x + 1) people attending." If there is another way feel free to point it out.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## [Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TyVZpQ?p=preview)

To do this you'll want a reference that stores the number of people attending, and you may optionally want to keep track of who is attending.

### Data Structure

```
{
  "attending" : {
    "number" : 2,
    "people" : {
      "-K3xTAvLPVLCc8AeDOPy" : {
        "first" : "Chris"
      },
      "-K3xTCXIBkevmfVlARn9" : {
        "first" : "Ben"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### View Current Number

To view the current number of people attending, we use the factory `NumberAttending` to return a `$firebaseObject` of https://so-examples.firebaseio.com/33861920/attending/number and add it to the scope.

**Controller**

```
  $scope.numberAttending = NumberAttending;
```

**Services**

```
.factory("NumberAttending", function($firebaseObject, Ref) {
  var numberRef = Ref.child('attending').child('number');
  return $firebaseObject(numberRef);
})
.factory("PeopleAttending", function($firebaseArray, Ref) {
  var peopleRef = Ref.child('attending').child('people');
  return $firebaseArray(peopleRef);
})
.factory('Ref', function() {
    return new Firebase("https://so-examples.firebaseio.com/33861920")
})
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="list card">
    <div class="item item-calm item-divider">Deliver Meals on Saturday</div>
    <div class="item item-body">
        <p>Hey, there are {{numberAttending.$value}} people attending.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

### Incrementing attendance

You'll want a way to increment the people attending that won't fail two people sign up at the same time. [Firebase.transaction()](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/transaction.html) is great for this.

To get the reference of https://so-examples.firebaseio.com/33861920/attending/number we use `$ref()` on our service:

```
var numAttendingRef = NumberAttending.$ref();
```

Then using that reference we perform the transaction:

```
numAttendingRef.transaction(function (current_value) {
  return (current_value || 0) + 1;
});
```

Comment: Yes, I'll add them to the answer for clarity.

Comment: Updated it. Just let me know if you have any questions. Thanks!

Comment: I apologize, can't quite figure out how to format comments.

Comment: My controller seems to be broken still. Am I mistaken in thinking it should be this:     `.controller('HelpCtrl', function($scope, NumberAttending) {
$scope.numberAttending = NumberAttending;
});`

Comment: Is your implementation hosted somewhere that I can look over? Is it working for you in the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TyVZpQ?p=preview)?

Comment: At the moment no, I will try to put it up on plunker for you. Your code works on plunker but when I try to replicate it with my own app it doesn't seem to work. I'll get mine up on plunker as soon as possible.

Comment: I have edited the original post to include a plunker for my app.

Comment: Okay, I connected a few things to make the Plunker work, but didn't change anything substantial. It looks like you haven't entered your firebase url. It should be in the `Ref` factory. Right now it says `return new Firebase("myfirebase")` but you need to replace myfirebase with your url. Also, here's an [updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kYGEIEwkUxGbkZ870gGQ?p=preview) with your version working.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't exactly sure what I was missing to make the app work with plunker. 

Anyway, it was only myfirebase for an example. In my own code I have the proper address. Do you need that?

Comment: Yes, I would need that to see what is going on. Your security rules should keep everything safe.

Comment: You need to put `{{numberAttending.$value}}` in your `tab-help.html` file instead of `{{numberAttending}}`. Also you'll want to only put `https://blistering-inferno-3724.firebaseio.com/` in the `Ref` factory and exclude the `attending/number`.

Comment: Actually I just figured it out, I was putting in the link incorrectly. When I copied it over for you I noticed that the /attending/number shouldn't have been there.

Comment: Awesome, that's great!